# Is there a benefit to using Swift or Java over NativeScript?

Tags: mobile, nativescript

From my understanding, if you want to develop a multi-platform app, it makes more sense to just use NativeScript or some other hybrid language. So would there be a point in using swift, objective-c, java, etc over something like NativeScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the long run, I would love to choose swift/java over cross-platform framework. Even though with NativeScript, React Native or Xamarin, they all render the real UI Component from native API but I think there is still a gap between performances of swift/java and cross-platform.

Cross-platform is perfect for small or medium apps, or companies who have limited human resources as cost for developing and maintaining native apps is quite high. However, the cross-platform apps won't be as stable as native apps, so if you want to have a feature-rich apps, swift/java would be better. Moreover, I don't know much about React Native but you have full access to native API in NativeScript with JavaScript.

Technically, you can do everything swift/java can do in NativeScript. However, there are something in native API (e.g UI components, native function, etc.) that might take lots of efforts to access as it's quite tricky to translate swift/obj-C/java to javascript. Fortunately, there are many [plugins](http://nativescript.rocks/new.php) or [code snippets](http://www.nativescriptsnacks.com/) made by community that might be helpful.

That's my personal idea.

Comment: Depends on your app. There are some apps that cannot be done in Nativescript. For example apps that require draw commands - at least not easily w/o resorting to native api.  Also I've found {N} to be slower than true native apps. On the flip-side developing has been faster I think and cross-platform I hope (i'm on one platform right now - but should be switching soon). Also maintaining one source code is easier. In a nutshell - if your app doesn't require draw api - i would recommend {N}. I'm sure the performance problems will be fixed in the future.